# Find xPath of IHTMLElement

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath

I'm writing a small application. Where on mouse click i get IHTMLElement. Now I have to find out the xPath for that particular element.

What I tried is first I got the parent of that particular element and then got all children OF that parent in IHTMLCollections. Now I iterate the collection and tried finding out the index of the IHTMLElement I clicked.

The issue I face here is the address on the element I click and the address from the collection of the same IHTMLElement is not matching.

Kindly help me out in finding the xPath of the IHTMLElement.

Comment: 1) Show your attempts so far. 2) Please explain what you need the XPath *for*.

Comment: can you show us the page source?